# Can I invoke POJO method asynchronously in java ee 7 without using EJB?

Tags: asynchronous, pojo, java-ee-7

I would like to invoke a method that send an email. This method has void return type so I do not need to use the Future interface for handling the result. All the Java ee 7 documentation cover this topic if you use session beans.
Is there any way to use the async approach for a normal method invocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `java.util.concurrent.Future` and `java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture`to call your method asynchronously.

```
Future<Integer> futureInteger = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getInteger(parameter));
```